# Unsubscribe fromEvent RxJs using Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject, takeuntil

can I unsubscribe fromtEvent RxJs using takeUntil with Subject inside?
My example code is like this:

```
private _closed$: Subject = new Subject<boolean>();
fromEvent(document, 'mousedown')
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._closed$));
```

But the problem is my linting shows me the error:

```
Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Event, unknown>'.
  Type 'Observable<unknown>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<Event>): Observable<unknown>'.ts(2345)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Subject type missing in declaration

```
private _closed$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
fromEvent(document, 'mousedown')
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._closed$));
```

Answer (score 0):

The subject can be of type `void`. Something like `close$ = new Subject<void>()`
And then on `OnDestroy()` you can call `close$.next();` and `close$.complete()` to trigger the notification for `takeUntil()`